# "snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: control 2:0:0:PCM Playback Volume:0 is already present" error every time I boot

Tags: drivers, 20.04, sound, kubuntu, pulseaudio

I am new to Linux and not sure where to look for logs and stuff. Every time I boot, I get a black screen with this error message, which comes up for a second:

```
snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: control 2:0:0:PCM Playback Volume:0 is already present
```

My sound is working fine however. Maybe even better than when I was on Windows.

Here is the output of `arecord -l`:

```
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC3204 Analog [ALC3204 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Output of `lspci | grep -i audio`:

```
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller (rev 30)
```

Here are my system's specs (do tell me if any more info is needed):

- Operating System: Kubuntu 20.04
- KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.5
- KDE Frameworks Version: 5.68.0
- Qt Version: 5.12.8
- Kernel Version: 5.11.0-37-generic
- OS Type: 64-bit
- Processors: 8 × Intel® Core™ i5-1035G1 CPU @ 1.00GHz
- Memory: 7.4 GiB of RAM

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Can you boot the machine? If so, does everything work? If so, then it's nothing to worry about. That is an output related to your audio hardware and I'm sure I have gotten that in one of my arch or ubuntu installations. Right now in arch I get a lot of ACPI errors that are nothing to worry about.

Comment: yeah everything is working I was just worried it might cause problems in the future thanks!